# File Browser in C for POSIX OS

Tags: c

I have created a file browsing UI for an embedded device. On the embedded side, I am able to get all files in a directory off the hard disk and return stats such as name, size, modified, etc. This is done using `opendir` and `closedir` and a `while` loop that goes through every file until no files are left.

This is cool, until file counts reach large quantities. I need to implement pagination and sorting. Suppose I have 10,000 files in a directory - how can I possibly go through this amount of files and sort based on size, name, etc, without easily busting the RAM (about 1mb of RAM... !). Perhaps something already exists within the Hard Drive OS or drivers?

Comment: "*Suppose I have 10,000 files in a directory*" you do not want such many files in one directory for other reasons (number of inodes, for example). So change the program's design to evenly distribute the files over several sub-directories or even a tree of sub-directories.

Comment: This is out of my control.

Comment: 1MB is not much RAM for a device that needs to handle a table of 10,000 items, regardless of where they come from. You have 100 bytes per item. Filenames are typically allowed to be up to 255 bytes long, although the average is much shorter. If you can't have all your items in memory at once, you'll have to do an external sort (i.e. put the data into a temp file in the format you want to have it displayed, then sort the temp file). This won't be easy.

Comment: I suggest you split the task in half like this: first, forget that you have to gather the data from the directory and just imagine you have it all in a single file, in the best possible format for what you're about to do. Then figure out how implement the interactive sorted display of that file. That's the first half done. Now figure out how to create that file with `opendir`, `readdir`, `stat`, etc. That's the second half, and it should be the easy part.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley appreciate the advice. I've thought it through in my head and I'd basically be writing an SQL table with sorting

Comment: I forgot to mention earlier: if you have or can create some swap space, you can just do the whole thing in your process memory. Performance will gradually get worse as the size increases, but it was going to do that anyway.

Comment: 1 megabyte of RAM is really not enough for a POSIX system. Quite probably, the kernel would need *much more* than that. Consider cheap [RaspberryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) boards, they have a *gigabyte* of RAM. So upgrade your hardware, or downgrade your software and system.

Comment: You can use a trie. You will surely not get out of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two suggestions, both of which have small memory footprint. The first will use no more memory that the number of results you wish to return for the request. It's a constant-time O(1) memory - it only depends on the size of the result set but is ultimately quadratic time (or worse) if the user really does page through all results:

You are only looking for a small paged result (e.g the r=25 entries). You can generate these by scanning through all filenames and maintaining a sorted list of items you will return, using an insertion sort of length r and for each file inserted, only retain the first r results. (In practice you would not insert the file F if it is lower than the r<sup>th</sup> entry).

How would you generate the 2<sup>nd</sup> page of results? You already know the 25th file from the previous request - so during the scan ignore all entries that are before that. (You'll need to work harder if sorting on fields with duplicates)

The upside is the minimum memory required - the memory needed is not much larger than the r results you wish to return (and can even be less if you don't cache the names). The downside is generating the complete result will be quadratic in time in terms of the number of total files you have. In practice people don't sort results then page through all pages, so this may be acceptable.

If your memory budget is larger (e.g. fewer than 10000 files) but you still don't have enough space to perform a simple in-memory sort of all 10000 filenames then seekdir/telldir is your friend. i.e. create an array of longs by streaming readdir and using telldir to capture the position of each entry. (you might even be able to compress the delta between each telldir to a 2 byte short). As a minimal implementation you can then sort 'em all with clib's sort function and writing your own callback to convert a location into a comparable value. Your call back will use seekdir twice to read the two filenames.

The above approach is overkill - you just sorted *all* entries and you only needed one page of ~25, so for fun why not read up on Hoare's QuickSelect algorithm and use a version of it to identify the results within the required range. You can recursive ignore all entries outside the required range and only sort the entries between the first and last entry of the results.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an [external sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting), that's a sort done with external resources, usually on disk. The Unix `sort` command does this. Typically this is done with an [external merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting#External_merge_sort).

The algorithm is basically this. Let's assume you want to dedicate 100k of memory to this (the more you dedicate, the fewer disk operations, the faster it will go).

1. Read 100k of data into memory (ie. call `readdir` a bunch).
2. Sort that 100k hunk in-memory.
3. Write the hunk of sorted data to its own file on disk.

   - You can also use offsets in a single file.
4. GOTO 1 until all hunks are sorted.

Now you have X hunks of 100k on disk an each of them are sorted. Let's say you have 9 hunks. To keep within the 100k memory limit, we'll divide the work up into the number of hunks + 1. 9 hunks, plus 1, is 10. 100k / 10 is 10k. So now we're working in blocks of 10k.

5. Read the first 10k of each hunk into memory.
6. Allocate another 10k (or more) as a buffer.
7. Do an [K-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm#K-way_merging) on the hunks.

   1. Write the smallest in any hunk to the buffer. Repeat.
   2. When the buffer fills, append it to a file on disk.
   3. When a hunk empties, read the next 10k from that hunk.
8. When all hunks are empty, read the resulting sorted file.

You might be able to find a library to perform this for you.

---

Since this is obviously overkill for the normal case of small lists of files, only use it if there are more files in the directory than you care to have in memory.

Both in-memory sort and external sort begin with the same step: start calling `readdir` and writing to a fixed-sized array. If you run out of files before running out of space, just do an in-memory quicksort on what you've read. If you run out of space, this is now the first hunk of an external sort.